# How to change top-level package dependencies in MeteorJS?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm revisiting "Discover Meteor" and ran into an error when installing the iron-router package. Currently running on MeteorJS v1.1.0.2. Here's the command line:

```
$mrt add iron-router
```

This caused all kinds of debugger errors, which I thought could be related to a dependency crash. However,

```
$mrt remove iron-router
```

leaves a dependency reference somewhere. Hence, the server crashes.

Anybody know where I can find the proper location for editing out the offending dependency?

Comment: Do not use `mrt`, it's deprecated, use `meteor add iron-router` instead.

Comment: Thanks @saimeunt. I first used meteor add iron-router and got a "no such package" error. Hence mrt add iron-router.

Comment: Oops, that's actually `meteor add iron:router`, with a colon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be:

```
meteor add iron:router
```

As for removing old packages, you can edit the .meteor/packages file directly and remove anything you don't want.  If you want to go back to how the project was at the start (in other words, make it look like it was after you first ran the `meteor create` command) leave these packages:

- meteor-platform
- autopublish
- insecure